# how to pick top 2 rows in a table based on the indicator

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sample data like this

```
Declare @table Table 
(
  ID INT,
  Value VARCHAR(10),
  Is_failure int
)

insert into @table(ID, Value, Is_failure) values (1, 'Bits', 0)
insert into @table(ID, Value, Is_failure) values (2, 'Ip', 0)
insert into @table(ID, Value, Is_failure) values (3, 'DNA', 0)
insert into @table(ID, Value, Is_failure) values (6, 'DCP', 1)
insert into @table(ID, Value, Is_failure) values (8, 'Bits', 0)
insert into @table(ID, Value, Is_failure) values (11, 'calc', 0)
insert into @table(ID, Value, Is_failure) values (14, 'DISC', 0)
insert into @table(ID, Value, Is_failure) values (19, 'DHCP', 1)
```

Looks like this:

```
ID  Value   Is_failure
1   Bits    0
2   Ip      0
3   DNA     0
6   DCP     1
8   Bits    0
11  calc    0
14  DISC    0
19  DHCP    1
```

Data continuous like this ... I need to fetch top 2 records along with Is_failure whenever Is_failure = 1 comes if it is 0 no need to pick up .

Sample output:

```
ID  Value   Is_failure
2   Ip      0
3   DNA     0
6   DCP     1
11  calc    0
14  DISC    0
19  DHCP    1
```

Suggest on this I have tried with `having count(*)` and other things but not fruitful.

Comment: in case before `Is_failure=1` there are only 1 or 0 records where `Is_failure=0` what is expected result?

Comment: anything we can bring before is_failure = 1 but always before 1 all are zeros only

Comment: maybe something using `Row_Number`? Find all row numbers for records with `Is_failure=1`. Then with cursor try to select top 2 records also using `Row_Number`

Comment: I have used Row_number and cross apply also but not getting expected that's the reason I have posted here to get the better solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this query

```
Declare @tmptable Table 

(
ID INT,
Value VARCHAR(10),
Is_failure int,
rowNum int
)
Declare @continuousRows int =2
insert into @tmptable
select *,ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id) from @table
;with cte1 as
(select *
from @tmptable t
where (select sum(Is_failure) from @tmptable t1 where t1.rowNum between t.rowNum-@continuousRows and t.rowNum
having count(*)=@continuousRows+1)=1
and t.Is_failure=1

) 
,cte2 as
(
select t.* from @tmptable t
join cte1 c on t.rowNum between c.rowNum-@continuousRows and c.rowNum

)
select c.ID,value,Is_failure from cte2   c
```

Comment: if I want to get top 10 records of the table from Is failure =1 then it is not giving exact output

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions for this:

```
select id, value, is_failure
from (select t.*,
             lead(Is_failure) over (order by id) as next_if,
             lead(Is_failure, 2) over (order by id) as next_if2
      from @table t
     ) t
where 1 in (Is_failure, next_if, next_if2)
order by id;
```

You can simplify this with a windowing clause:

```
select id, value, is_failure
from (select t.*,
             max(is_failure) over (order by id rows between current row and 2 following) as has_failure
      from @table t
     ) t
where has_failure > 0
order by id;
```